# AlertDialog to only stay open on condition not working

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have the following code and only want my positive button to close if a certain condition is met, otherwise I want it to stay open with the same data:

```
  protected void showInputDialog() {

        final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phrase_input_layout, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        dialogBuilder.setTitle("Create new phrase flashcard");
        dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Done", (dialog, whichButton) -> {
            SubmissionState state = addCardToDocument(dialogView);
            if (state == SubmissionState.SUBMITTED_WITH_RESULTS_FOUND){
                dialog.dismiss();
            } else {
                // still stay open here, but it still closes...
            }
        });
        dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", (dialog, whichButton) -> Log.d("DEBUG", "Cancelled creating new phrase card."));
        AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
        b.show();
    }
```

However, it appears no matter what, when I press the positive button, the dialogBuilder will close, regardless if it goes into the else statement or not; also, even if I comment out all of the code for the `setPositiveButton` it will still dismiss the dialog!

What am I doing wrong?

If it's relevant, here is my `phrase_input_layout` too:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/phrase_translate_radio_group_header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:text="@string/select_translation_mode"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/phrase_translate_radio_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/phrase_manual_translation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/manual_translation" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/eng_auto_translation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/english_auto_translation" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/swe_auto_translation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/swedish_auto_translation" />
</RadioGroup>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/englishPhrase"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:hint="@string/english_phrase" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/swedishPhrase"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:hint="@string/swedish_phrase" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that by using the provided `setPositiveButton` method. If you set a listener using this method, then whenever the button is clicked the listener is invoked and then the dialog is dismissed. I don't see a way to override this behavior as `AlertDialog`  internally uses an `AlertController` object that implements this behavior.

So what you can do is use custom buttons instead of the default ones.

For example, you could add two buttons at the bottom of `phrase_input_layout` xml.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/negativeButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/buttonSeparator"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/separator" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/positiveButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Set click listeners for these buttons. Like so:

```
AlertDialog dialog;
protected void showInputDialog() {
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.phrase_input_layout, null);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

    dialogBuilder.setTitle("Create new phrase flashcard");
    
    Button positiveButton = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.positiveButton);
    Button negativeButton = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.negativeButton);

    positiveButton.setText("Create new phrase flashcard");
    positiveButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        SubmissionState state = addCardToDocument(dialogView);
            if (state == SubmissionState.SUBMITTED_WITH_RESULTS_FOUND){
                dialog.dismiss();
            } else {
            }
    });

    negativeButton.setText("Cancel");
    negativeButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        dialog.dismiss()
    });

    dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```